# Por que o padrão de um modificador de acesso é "protected" no .NET?

Tags: .net

Ao menos que eu esteja enganado, o padrão de quando não é definido um modificador de uma classe, por exemplo, é assumido o `protected`:

```
class LoremIpsum {
    ...
}
```

Há alguma razão especial para isso? qual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O modificador padrão de acesso para uma classe não é o [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx). É o [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx).

O modificador padrão de acesso para um método de uma classe é o [`private`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx).

Segundo [resposta do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521492/1314276), isto se deve pela segurança da linguagem primar pela maior restrição possível.

Tem mais:

- **Namespaces** são [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) por padrão;
- **Interfaces** são [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) por padrão, mas seus membros são [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx);
- **Types** são [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) por padrão;
- **Membros de `struct`** são [`private`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) por padrão;
- **Enums** são [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) por padrão, sendo seus membros sempre [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx);

Especificação da linguagem: http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=7029

Comment: Além de `protected` nem ao menos ser possível dentro de um namespace... só é possível definir um tipo `protected` como subtipo de outro tipo.

Comment: E eu estava enganado :) Muito obrigado pela agilidade e qualidade da sua resposta. Achei um link complementar [no MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)